# I am trying to create multiple files in the same folder with different names using python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to create 5 files all in the same folder with different names but when I run I only get one file.

```
a = 1
x = datetime.now()

while a < 5:
    a += 1
    path = r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Newfolder'
    file_name = x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%f=HDTV.txt')
        
     with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), 'w') as fp:
         fp.write('this is a test')
```

Comment: x is determined just at beginning (outside the loop). You should put the `x` inside the loop, and possibly add a `time.sleep(0.01)` just to be sure you are not doing things to quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As told @Giacomo, the problem is that the timestamp do not depend on the loop:

```
a = 1
x = datetime.now

while a < 5:
    a += 1
    path = r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Newfolder'
    file_name = x().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%f=HDTV.txt')
        
     with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), 'w') as fp:
         fp.write('this is a test')
```

Comment: look deeply at the code, `now` will be called inside the loop at each step. It is not elegant, but explain well the difference between the 2 call position

Comment: hehe, overlooked that ^^ so for readability, maybe I'd put `datetime.now()` instead of `x()` there ;-)

Comment: Even this creates only one file.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost:

> **`x` should be present inside the `while` loop as you need the current time in every iteration.**

Also, I think that there is not much of time difference between creating the files and that is why the current created file overrides the previous file (*as the timestamp is same and so are the filenames*).

I have 2 suggestions:

##### 1. Using Distinct filenames

My suggestion is to use that variable `a` in the filename so that you have distinct filenames.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
path = os.getcwd()
a = 1
while a < 5:
    x = datetime.now()
    file_name = f"{x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S-%f=HDTV')}_{a}.txt"
    
    with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(f'this is a test')

    a += 1
```

##### 2. Using [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Otherway is you can use `time.sleep()` to pause the execution for some time (depending on your requirement) so that the filenames are different in each iteration.

Comment: This is not the right way, beacuse the problem was not the speed of the loop but the timestamp do not depend on the loop itself.

Comment: But the timestamp is calculated everytime inside the loop. Right ?

Comment: My comment refer to the description, not the code, code is right.